# Rewrite PHP URL for Node.js

Tags: node.js, url-rewriting, express

I need to rewrite this URL with Node:

```
/single.php?articleID=123
```

to this:

```
/article/123
```

This is because a company I work with already printed out QR codes with said URL for the old software. Now that their software got rewritten in Node, no QR code works anymore. How can I support this old URL with Node? I tried setting up a route for it:

```
app.get('/single.php?articleID=:id', log.logRequest, auth.checkAuth, function (request, reponse) {
  response.send(request.params.id);
});
```

But it just responds this:

```
Cannot GET /single.php?articleID=12
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express routes are just for paths, but you should be able to route `single.php` and get `articleID` from [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query).

```
app.get('/single.php', log.logRequest, auth.checkAuth, function (request, reponse) {
    response.send(request.query.articleID);
});
```

If you want to require the query parameter for the route, you can create a custom middleware for it:

```
function requireArticleID(req, res, next) {
    if ('articleID' in req.query) {
        next();
    } else {
        next('route');
    }
}

app.get('/single.php', requireArticleID, ..., function (request, reponse) {
    // ...
});
```

`next('route')` is discussed under [Application Routing](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB).